# Auto-Update for a Windows application

Tags: c++, c, windows

Is there an open source project that allows for an auto-update of windows binaries?  The [Luau](http://luau.sourceforge.net/) update library is very similar to what I'm looking for but it was abandoned in 2005.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google [Omaha](http://google-opensource.blogspot.com/2009/04/google-update-goes-open-source.html) . But I have not tried it and don't know how easy it is to use.

Answer (score 11):

I was wondering the same thing and I took a look at [Omaha](http://code.google.com/p/omaha/) but it requires so many prerequisites (WiX, Python2.4, Scons etc..) that it frightened me away.

All I wanted was something simple so I also tried out [WinSparkle](http://winsparkle.org/) and it is incredibly simple compared to Omaha, I definitely recommend it! One further note about WinSparkle: If you using Visual C++ WinForms you can simply link in the lib just like in their native C++ setup [explanation](http://winsparkle.org/wiki/Doc/BasicSetup#BasicWinSparklesetup).

Comment: Actually [NetSparkle](http://netsparkle.codeplex.com/) might be more appropriate for a .NET project, also it seems to be kept more up to date than WinSparkle.

Comment: +1 for WinSparkle - we've just started using this and it's extremely easy to get going :-)

Answer (score 4):

There was a discussion here with some options
[How to best implement software updates on windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37030/how-to-best-implement-software-updates-on-windows)

In particual this http://winsparkle.org/ which I keep meaning to look at !

Answer (score 3):

There are two things I belive the Windows platform seriously lacks. One: A secured password store, and this

A central API to allow applications to register themselves so I dont get twenty million effing icons in my system tray as applications, that doubtless DO need to be updated, but also, are used very rarely, tell me how much bandwidth they've wasted downloading yet-another needless update.

Answer (score 1):

There is one:
I am the author :)
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/310530/Target-Eye-Revealed-part-1-Target-Eyes-Unique-Auto